# Why is my proof that $(A^m)^{-1} = (A^{-1})^m $ not rigorous?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For our tutorial we were asked to proof that $ (A^m)^{-1} = (A^{-1})^m $ where A was any nonsingular matrix. My proof was a proof by contradiction which went as follows: assume the statement does not hold, so
\begin{equation}
(A^m)^{-1} \neq (A^{-1})^m
\end{equation}
Then we can multiply both the left and right hand side by $A^m$ without destroying the inequality because $A$ is nonsingular to find
\begin{align}
A^m (A^m)^{-1} &\neq A^m(A^{-1})^m \\
I &\neq A_1\,A_2\,A_3\cdots\,A_m\, A_m^{-1}A_{m-1}^{-1}A_{m-2}^{-1}A_1^{-1} \\
I &\neq I
\end{align}
with $A_1 = A_2 = \cdots = A_m$

From this I concluded that because my assumption that $(A^m)^{-1} \neq (A^{-1})^m$ led to a nonsensical conclusion, that $I \neq I$, the initial assumption cannot have been true.

Sadly, my TA told me that although my conclusion was correct, the proof was not rigorous which made me wonder what step I had taken that was not rigorous, unfortunately the only thing my TA could tell me was that it really was not rigorous without an explanation as to why it was not.

After our tutorial curiosity and a wish to improve got the better of me which made me decide to head to the mathematics stackexchange to see if the good people here

PS:
if you think you might have been my TA and are reading this then let it be known that you are a great TA and all your other explanations were very clear.

Comment: Seems correct to me. The only thing where you should be careful is this: you should give a reason why $A\neq B$ implies $CA \neq CB$ for a non-singular matrix $C$.

Comment: Another thing is that you would need to explain why $(A^m)^{-1}$ exists.  It just amounts to explaining why $A$ being nonsingular implies $A^m$ being nonsingular.  Other than that I think the proof is correct

Comment: Also, strictly speaking, the fact that $A^m (A^{-1})^m = I$ requires a proof by induction, at least I can't see anyway without it (also note that if you manage to prove this, then you have infact given a direct proof, and there is no need to argue by contradiction). The induction just makes the $\cdots$ part of your argument more complete.

Comment: Your TA might not like your notation and prefer a proof by induction

Comment: Why do you want to prove this by contradiction?  If you take what you've written and rearrange it a little, you'll have a much shorter direct proof.

Comment: @peek-a-boo my TA also kept saying that this could only be done through induction. Why is it that simple expanding both powers (for integers m) is not a proper proof that this reduces to I? since constantly the $A\,A^{-1}$ inbetween the two sequences is equal to $I$ and can then be ignored because they dissapear upon multiplication by $A$?

Comment: In my opinion, no need for induction (nor contradiction)

Comment: It's not a "proper" proof because the very definition of the symbol $A^m$ is given recursively as follows:  $A^1:= A$, and for $m\geq 2$, we define $A^m := (A^{m-1})\cdot A$. Since the definition is recursive, a super rigorous proof about anything involving powers should use induction. Usually in lectures/tutorials we may often write things like $A^m = \underbrace{A\cdots A}_{\text{$m$ times}}$, because this may look more familiar. But you should ask yourself, what does the "$\cdots$" really mean. This is only given meaning using the recursive definition.

Comment: Most of the time when you are doing computations using the symbol $\cdots$, this technically would need to be justified using induction - what rule of inference allows you to conclude $A_1\,A_2\,A_3\cdots\,A_m\, A_m^{-1}A_{m-1}^{-1}A_{m-2}^{-1}A_1^{-1} = I$?  *However*, mathematicians tend to skip over this step and consider it to be understood.  Whether that's okay in your case is up to your TA.

Comment: @peek-a-boo This is getting philosophical, but I would argue that if we assume a fixed $m$, then the direct definition of $A^m$ (multiply $n$-times) is quite correct without any induction concept...

Comment: Of course, I'm only being super pedantic because you asked. Otherwise, the explanation "constantly the products $AA^{-1}$ in the middle become $I$" makes sense to me, and I'm sure everyone understands it. Since this is I presume an introductory linear algebra course, you should worry (atleast once throughout your math journey) about such details. But once you have gone through this routine justification a few times, the rigorous induction argument becomes as obvious as the intuitive $\cdots$ argument.

Comment: Chiming in with Bananach, peek-a-boo and Jair Taylor. The possibly non-rigorous step is that with the ellipsis $\cdots$. It is kinda clear what's going on, but when I do an "obvious" step like that I tell my students that we really should do an induction here. I do it myself a few times when teaching their first course in abstract algebra. Some learn it right away, some others think it is obvious, but the reason why it is obvious may not be clear to them :-)

Comment: Here there is the extra obstacle of how did you define $A^m$ in the first place? If doing full Peano, it was recursive, and you need induction. I have seen (and used) lecture notes where there is some cheating at this point. I would say it depends on the style of the text, whether this is relevant or not. At least to some extent.

Comment: For comparison, just two weeks ago I did induction to prove the partial sum formula of a telescoping series. In addition to extra rigor the motivation was mostly pedagogical. To make them think through one more induction, and also to make the point that all sum formulas typically proven by induction can be rewritten as telescoping sums :-)

Comment: Another possibility is that the question was intended to be understood as, If $A$ is non-singular, show that $A^m$ is non-singular, with $(A^m)^{-1} = (A^{-1})^m$.  Taken in this light, the first step that relies on $A^m$ being non singular to conclude $A^m(A^m)^{-1} \neq A^m (A^{-1})^m$ fails and your argument would be circular.  Perhaps what was intended was to use associativity (and induction if need be) to show $(A^m) ((A^{-1})^m) = I$.